# Can I protect a single Worksheet in excel to make it unviewable for other?

Tags: excel

I have a shift planner and it can be seen/used by anyone in order to mark down their shifts. I now have created a new Worksheet that calculates how many vacation days each employee has left in order to have a better overview. Since it is law that it should not be viewed by other employees,
I thought of giving that sheet a Password. When I set the Password however, anyone can still see the contents of the sheet.

How can I set it up, so that the sheet cannot be viewed as long as the Password is not correct?

Comment: I did this by hiding all the columns and then when setting the password not allowing editing...

Comment: Please keep in mind that if this is the law you are on thin ice here. I suggest you do not in any way try and block the other employees from this sheet but instead place this sheet in a different file that they can't access. All Excel files are easy to break in to. Hidden sheets is easy to unhide, passwords are easy to break and all VBA code that "does something" can be undone by a skilled person. Don't do this if this is the law. I can't emphasize this enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that sheet "very hidden".

Steps to do:

- save document as xlsm (with macros)
- open the vba-editor (ALT + F11)
- set the sheet to very hidden - "very hidden" means that it is not possible to unhide the sheet via the Excel-GUI (like a hidden sheet) - but only via the VBE-GUI.

[image]

To prevent users from unhiding via the VBA-Editor:

- Select Extras - VBA Project properties (Eigenschaften von VBA-Projekt)
- Go to the protection tab and choose to lock project plus add password.

(This protection only works if the file is stored as xlsm.)

Please be aware that there are lots of sources that explain how to crack the VBE-password. If someone wants to see the sheet he or she will be able to. An Excel-file will never be 100 % safe.